# Old employer H1-B Visa stamp (valid) on now-expired passport. Can I travel with new I-797 which was approved before Renewing passort?

Tags: h1-visa, passport

I had H-1B stamped in Dec 2021, valid until 2024. I changed employer in Mar 2022, have I-797A, Valid until 2024. Renewed my passport in May 2023.

Can I now travel out of USA and return using my old passport with old employer visa stamp, new employer I-797A (applied before renewing passport) and Renewed passport?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you carry the old passport with unexpired visa with you, you should be fine. You don't need to reissue the visa sticker if you changed the employer, you just need the old visa (as long as it is valid) and the latest I797A. Make sure to carry the original with you.